# Does exist in asp.net an annotation for deny access to one user or role to a method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, annotations

I guess if in asp.net mvc exixts possibility to exclude some user from access to an action method.

As well the "authorize" annotazion allows users to acces some action methods:

```
[Authorize(Users="*")]   
public ActionResult method1() { ... }
```

a similar annotation for exclude, for example:

```
[Deny(Users="user1")]        
public ActionResult method1() { ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is, but you can create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` as simple as this:

```
public class DenyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   private string[] deniedusers;  
   public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] users)  
   {  
      this.deniedusers = users;  
   }  
   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)  
   {  
      // you could improve this
      return !this.deniedusers.Contains(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);  
   }  
}
```

Or a simpler solution:

```
public class DenyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return !base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to use it exactly as in your example:

```
[Deny(Users="user1,user2")]
```

Comment: Thanks SmartDev for your answer and sorry but I've seen it a bit late.. I had solved the problem with anotheer strategy a bit more trivial.. I used "User.Identity.Name" in the method..
Again thank you for your solutions that I will surely consider for the future